# How to pass a function in a parameter and then call that function from an object

Tags: c++, function, syntax

I have a `Sprite` class that has an `int update(int key)` method.

I also have another class (`SpriteManager`) that has a list of all `Sprites`. I want to add a method to this class that takes a method, and an int as an argument. I then want to iterate through this list and call that method on all of the objects. However, I cannot find any way to do this. I know how to pass function as parameters, and also how to call ***specific*** methods on objects out of context, but I don't know how to do both.

An example of using this method would be something like:

`sm.tellSpritesToDoSomething(Sprite::update, 42);`

Where `sm` is a `SpriteManager`.

Comment: You have 3 options: ::std::function, ::std::bind and templates, whichever you prefer.

Comment: Do you by any chance know which is fastest?

Comment: Usually it is the template method, as it is simplest.

Comment: How would I use templates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check [std::bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind), [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [placeholders](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/placeholders). And always remember that method itself is not enough, you need to pass object which will be used as this inside. For example

```
sm.tellSpritesToDoSomething(std::bind(&Sprite::update, _1, 42));
```

To other ways to do this are to use member function pointers (either explicitly or via templates):

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

struct Sprite {
    int update(int i) { return i; }
};

struct SpriteManager {
    std::vector<Sprite> sprites;
    template <typename F>
    void tellSpritesToDoSomething(F f, int i) {
        for (auto& sprite: sprites)
        {
            (sprite.*f)(i);
        }
    }
    void tellSpritesToDoSomething2(int (Sprite::*f)(int), int i) {
        for (auto& sprite: sprites)
        {
            (sprite.*f)(i);
        }
    }
    void tellSpritesToDoSomething3(std::function<int(Sprite&)> f) {
        std::for_each(sprites.begin(), sprites.end(), f);
    }
};

int main() {
    SpriteManager sm;
    sm.sprites.emplace_back();
    sm.sprites.emplace_back();
    sm.sprites.emplace_back();
    sm.tellSpritesToDoSomething(&Sprite::update, 42);
    sm.tellSpritesToDoSomething2(&Sprite::update, 42);
    using std::placeholders::_1;
    sm.tellSpritesToDoSomething3(std::bind(&Sprite::update, _1, 42));
}
```

Comment: Are these methods fast? I may have to call these methods hundreds of times a second, and I want it to be as smooth as possible.

Comment: Hundred of times a second is very low number for most of desktop/server cpus. Start with this and worry about faster alternatives only when you can prove with profiler that this is your bottleneck.

Comment: Alright thank you. A user above (who replied to my question) mentioned using templates. Do you know how I could do this?

Comment: @KhanPower The first one is using a template. You can also combine the template approach with the `std::for_each` method. The template approach is potentially marginally faster but marginally slower to compile (it probably has to go in a header file).

Comment: @TomaszKłak You don't need templates, when you _know_ what type your parameters are going to be. I've envisioned them for taking lambda objects.